# Multiple textures with load Collada. Still limited to just one?

Tags: three.js, webgl, collada

I have been working with the `Three.js` module and the `ColladaLoader.js` functionality for a few weeks now and am getting pretty confident with what is 
going on.

Up until today I have been loading in models of various complexity in to my code with no problems.

I put up an example of my code here.

http://ec2-54-213-35-209.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

The model is quite small and in the middle of the grid so need to zoom in to see it.

This is the error from the web console :

`Error: WebGL: DrawElements: bound vertex attribute buffers do not have sufficient size for given indices from the bound element array @ http://ec2-54-213-35-209.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/three.min.js:455`

So the elements list is messed up somehow when the collada model is brought in. It ends up missing a part.

If I set the material of the entire object manually with something like,

```
setMaterial(result.scene, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000}));
```

Then object in the scene is fine and I get no errors so I am pretty sure this is 
texture related.

I am pretty sure my code works since I have been loading other models fine. I think this will however be the first model that had multiple textures.

Texture Atlas and a single texture is a better solution anyway when it comes to glelement calls, right?

Answer (score 0):

it's may be to late for the answer , but it was actually a problem from the colladaLoader .

2 days ago , an update has been released for threejs (dev branch v65)

now the loader is able to handle complex model with multi-textures on each material.

Hope it helps you